# Pywinauto type_keys() omits "%" in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

When attempting to input a string `'customer asked for 30% discount'` to a form by using `type_keys()` in Pywinauto 0.6.5, the output it sends is `'customer asked for 30 discount"` omitting `'%'`.

Tried escape character:

1. `control.type_keys('customer asked for 30%% discount',with_spaces=True)`
2. `control.type_keys('customer asked for 30\% discount',with_spaces=True)`

But it still omits the `'%'`

When printing data in console string outputs correctly. So it is not a Python 3.7 issue.

Comment: Try using `\x25` in place of the `%` character,

Comment: @martineau, tried `\x25` in place of the `%` - issue still persists. Omits `\x25` resulting into string - `.. 30 discount.` This is a 'type_keys()' issue because typing `%` from keyboard directly into the form works as expected.

Comment: After diving into keyboard.py found this comment line
`# it is an escaped modifier e.g. {%}, {^}, {+}`
which solved my issue.

Below is the line that will allow to output '%' as a character into a form in pywinauto.
`control.type_keys('customer asked for 30{%} discount',with_spaces=True)`

Comment: @Redem that's great you figured it out. Please post this as an answer and accept it (gray check box under voting buttons at the left side). This will indicate for other the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: `.set_edit_text()` might be useful for some controls like edit box. It inputs the text at once without key-by-key typing though it doesn't support modifiers and doesn't require to escape them.

Answer (score 5):

As Redem already found, some special symbols must be escaped this way:

```
 control.type_keys('customer asked for 30{%} discount', with_spaces=True)
```

or method `.set_edit_text()` can be used for edit box control:

```
control.set_edit_text(r'customer asked for 30% discount')
```

Comment: thanks, helped to resolve the "C:\Program Files (x86)" path issue

Answer (score 0):

here's a little utility I use to prep passwords when using pywinauto.handler.type_keys():

```
password = 'cJ/Dy}(4H%x!c{)6'
clean_pass = ''
for c in password:
    if c in ['(', ')', '{', '}', '%']:
        clean_pass += ('{' + c + '}')
    else:
        clean_pass += c
print(clean_pass)
```