# pywinauto escaping special characters

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am using [`type_keys()`](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.type_keys) on a combobox to upload files via a file dialog. As mentioned in [similar SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208079/pywinauto-type-keys-omits-in-string), this function omits certain special characters in the text that it actually types into the combobox. I'm resolving this by simply replacing every "specialchar" in that string with "{specialchar}". So far I've found the need to replace the following chars: + ^ % ( ).

I'm wondering where I can find the **complete list of characters that require this treatment**. I don't think it's [this list](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html#pywinauto-keyboard) because I'm not seeing, for example, the % symbol there. I also tried checking `keyboard.py` from the `keyboard` library but I don't know if it can be found there.

PS. I realize that instead of using `type_keys()`, for example, using `send_keys()` or `set_edit_text()`, the escaping of special characters might be done for me automatically. However, for various reasons, it looks like `type_keys()` works the best for my particular file dialog/situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full documentation: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html All special characters can be wrapped by `{}`

Comment: Are you talking about the section under "Available key codes"? I've linked to that page myself already, stating that I cannot find there, for example, the %, +, or parentheses.

Comment: Maybe this document is a bit incomplete. Yes, `%` can be entered by `{%}`.

Comment: Ok, what is the rule to figure out when a character must be surrounded by `{` and `}`? Is there a way to dynamically figure that out? Currently I have a tuple `chars_to_convert = ('+', '^', '%', '(', ')')` and right before my `type_keys()` I loop through those 5 chars and `replace()`. If I can either dynamically figure out what my complete `chars_to_convert` should be or I can set the complete tuple once and never again, that would help.

Comment: Well, sorry I misread the question. The full list is `keyboard.MODIFIERS + ['(', ')', '{', '}']`. It's good idea to add `raw=False` parameter to `type_keys` so True value will ignore any special sequence.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. Will add your comment as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Vasily said in his answer, you can use `keyboard.MODIFIERS` to get all characters that `type_keys()` didn't recognize. Here's a little function to deal with those:

```py
# Convert string with special characters to a way type_keys() can deal with.
def convert_str_input(string: str):

    # Stores the new output
    new = ''

    # Iters trough all charactes in the string
    for c in str(string):
        
        # Deal with all cases except curly brackets, encapsulating in curly brackets
        if c in list(keyboard.MODIFIERS) + ['(', ')']:
            new += ('{' + c + '}')
        
        # Deal with curly brackets, encapsulating in parentheses
        elif c in ['{', '}']:
            new += ('(' + c + ')')
        
        # Just place the character if it don't need treatment
        else:
            new += c
    return new
```